# C# open file with variable characters

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, streamreader

I have a few files named like:

1. 6327_1-SWD001-171016_1.txt
2. 6327_1-SWD011-181016_1.txt
3. 6327_1-SWD028-191016_1.txt

As you can see th SWD value swaps per file and I would like to know if there is a way to open a file without knowing the SWD value, something like this:

6327_1-SWD???-171016_1.txt

or does a `StreamReader` need the EXACT name of a file?

Comment: Which one of the files are you meant to open?

Comment: @JanneMatikainen: There's only one which matches (the one containing `_171016_`).

Comment: Yea sorry i meant I have several more on that date (17 october 2016)only the SWD001 changes

Comment: And my question remains. These seem to be log files and you are interested in a specific one on the specific date, how do *you* know which one it is? And how would you tell that information to the code that should open the file.

Comment: These are files to set in a machine to give him information what to do. These dates are the dates the product needs to be produced by the machine (so I can easily can get that information with `DateTime.Now`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

StreamReader needs the EXACT name of the file. You can, however, use [`Directory.GetFiles`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz42302f(v=vs.110).aspx) to find the file you are looking for:

```
var files = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Some\Directory", "6327_1-SWD???-171016_1.txt");  // C#

Dim files = Directory.GetFiles("C:\Some\Directory", "6327_1-SWD???-171016_1.txt")    ' VB
```

`files` then contains an array of all file names (including the path) matching your pattern. `Directory.GetFiles` supports the `*` and `?` wildcards.

(Unrelated side note: Check out `File.ReadLines`, `File.ReadAllLines` and `File.ReadAllText`. Usually, you don't *need* a StreamReader to read a text file's contents anymore. Note that those methods need the full file name as well.)

Comment: When I'm using this with the `????` in my string it gives an exception: Illegal characters in path.

Comment: @Bart88: Works fine on my machine. What line *exactly* are you using that returns the error?

Comment: It works now, Thank you very much for your help :) I thought `GetFiles` only works for by Directory